# Added memory in android monitor Memory management in android

Tags: android, memory-management

I have this application that, once I go through, there is approximately 4mb that gets added once redirected to the home page(home activity).

I have bitmaps and I do release them, I nullify all member variables at the onDestroy. I have used the GC in the android studio but it does not come back to around the same memory size of the first time that activity was called.

The process of my application is :
Login -> Home -> Image Capture -> Summary (click done at this point to return to Home)

Doing so add's approximately 4mb every run of this flow in the android monitor when you are back to the Home activity.

Is this normal, am I missing something? I have tried with leakcanary but I have not received anything from it(and yes I know its setup because I get the initial access request).

I think this is ridiculous because someone can use this application for 10times or maybe 20 000 times before resetting it and 20 000x 4mb that is way too big.

Answer (score 0):

While LeakCanary can be useful to find some memory leaks, I've found that Android Studio's tools are better (in my humble experience). I recommend you use the Android Studio's [HPROF Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-hprof.html) to try and find your leak. 

Go to the Memory Monitor do the chain of events that cause a leak and then click the Dump Java Heap button. After it's done it should automatically open your dumped heap snapshot. There, on the top right you should see the Analyzer Tasks tab, click it and run a memory leak detection.

 Unfortunately without some code to look at this is the best advice I can give you.

Comment: I have been using both leakcanary and android monitor. I found a leak with the analyser, fixed it. Still the same problem. I wanted to know if the 4mb are a regular thing for Android or its just my app. Sadly I can't post the code here as it's a confidentiality agreement.